# Returning empty instead of 0

Tags: mysql

My mySQL query below appears to work as I would expect, returning the tally of `single` people within 50 miles from a geographic coordinate input (represented by `$lat1` and `$lat2`). The values `lattitude` and `longitude` come from values already in my database.

The only problem I have now is that, assuming there is no one that meets the given criteria, I would like the tally to return 0. Instead I get an empty response.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as cnt,
(3959 * 
    acos(
        cos(radians({$lat1}))
        * cos(radians(lattitude)) 
        * cos(radians(longitude) - radians({$lon1}))
        + sin(radians({$lat1}))
        * sin(radians(lattitude))
    )
) AS distance 
    FROM members WHERE status = 'single' HAVING distance < 50
```

If it's important, I have my data fetched via `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);` where `$query` is the code you see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use ifnull

```
  SELECT ifnull(COUNT(*), 0) as cnt,
```

Comment: It's very strange. I'm still returning a blank result.

Comment: Yeah it turns out there was something weird with my API. Code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an error in the query, if you are using `count(*)` with another no aggregate column you should have given a `group by` which is missing.

Comment: Yes. There is definitely an error. How might I rewrite my query to ensure that `0` values show?